# Javascript: Calling object property says the object(declared with object literal) is undefined

Tags: javascript-objects

html:

```
<div class="odf_details" id="con_details_nttn_odf_details">
                    <span class="hidden_id">con_details_nttn_odf_details</span>
                    <span class="msg"></span>
                    <table border="1" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2 class="dtable" align="center" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th>NTTN ODF:</th>
                            <th>Tray</th>
                            <th>Port</th>
                            <th>Circuit Type</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="odf_data_tr">
                            <td class="odf_name_td">
                                <input class="odf_name" type="text" name="nttn_odf_name" disabled="disabled" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="odf_tray_td">
                                <select class="odf_tray" name="con_details_nttn_odf_tray">
                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="a" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_tray'] == 'a') echo 'selected'; ?> >A</option>
                                    <option value="b" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_tray'] == 'b') echo 'selected'; ?> >B</option>
                                    <option value="c" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_tray'] == 'c') echo 'selected'; ?> >C</option>
                                    <option value="c" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_tray'] == 'd') echo 'selected'; ?> >D</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td class="odf_ports_td" align="center">
                                <span class="hidden_info"><?php echo $services['con_details_nttn_odf_port'] ?></span>
                                1<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="1" />
                                2<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="2" />
                                3<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="3" />
                                4<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="4" />
                                5<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="5" />
                                6<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="6" />
                                7<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="7" />
                                8<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="8" />
                                9<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="9" />
                                10<input type="checkbox" name="con_details_nttn_odf_port" value="10" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="con_details_nttn_odf_circuit_type">
                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    <option value="primary" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_circuit_type'] == 'primary') echo 'selected'; ?> >Primary</option>
                                    <option value="secondary" <?php if ($services['con_details_nttn_odf_circuit_type'] == 'secondary') echo 'selected'; ?> >Secondary</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

I added a required javascript file later, there, I declared an object:

```
var odf_data = {
    num_ports_in_each_tray: 10,
    added_odfs_total: 0,
    must_update: false,
    uniq_ports_per_tray_collection: build_uniq_ports_collection()
};

function build_uniq_ports_collection() {
    var odf_ports = new Array(4);
    odf_ports['a'] = new Array(odf_data.num_ports_in_each_tray);
    odf_ports['b'] = new Array(odf_data.num_ports_in_each_tray);
    odf_ports['c'] = new Array(odf_data.num_ports_in_each_tray);
    odf_ports['b'] = new Array(odf_data.num_ports_in_each_tray);
    odf_names_array = new Array(); //odf names should be unique

    var error = '';
    $('div.odf_details').each(function() {
        //now we are inside each odf's immediate parent div
        var tray = $(this).find('td.odf_tray_td select.odf_tray :selected').val();
        var odf_name = $(this).find('td.odf_name_td input.odf_name').val();

        $(this).find('td.odf_ports_td input:checked').each(function() {
            var port = $(this).val();
            if (!error && odf_ports[tray][port] === undefined) {
                odf_ports[tray][port] = odf_name;
            } else {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
        if (odf_data.must_update) {
            alert('there were some errors in port, you must update and save');
        }
    });
    return odf_ports;
}
```

But it shows error in firebug console at exactly this line:

```
odf_ports['a'] = new Array(odf_data.num_ports_in_each_tray);

TypeError: odf_data is undefined
```

I am just thinking, why ? 
I defined the object right ? but then why it is reported as undefined ??
Any quick help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/ahebev/1/edit)

Comment: Post the rest of your code. That alone can't produce this error message.

Comment: @Blender, rest of the code contains 972 lines !

Comment: @Blender, please see now

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ahebev/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

Oh,
thanks everyone.
I got the solution.

Its basically the object is being called by a property before the definition finishes